# Angular is displaying null values in select element

Tags: angularjs, select

I have an array of values with possible `null`. AngularJS displays those by default as a value, but I want to skip those values entirely.

Is my only option to create a filter or is there any other solution out there?

My code:

```
var app = angular.module('fooapp', []);

app.controller('FooController', function($scope) {
    $scope.foo = [null, 'foo', 'bar'];
});

<body ng-app="fooapp">
    <div ng-controller="FooController">
        <select ng-model="foomodel" ng-options="f for f in foo"></select>
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's a plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZGbkbtQ2xNQuoaowUK5z?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using a filter:

```
<select ng-model="foomodel" ng-options="f for f in foo | filter: '!null'"></select>
```

Comment: In my opinion this is a ugly hack. I opened [a issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10892) for this in AngularJS project on GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<select ng-model="foomodel" ng-options="f for f in foo | filter:'!'+null"></select>
```